# PHP create_function with nested arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, create-function

I need to use `create_function` because the server the application is running on has an outdated version of PHP.

The issue is that the items I pass into `usort` are arrays and I need to sort by a value within the array:

```
$sort_dist = create_function( '$a, $b', "
    if( $a['order-dir'] == 'asc' ) {
        return $a['distance'] > $b['distance'];
    }
    else {
        return $a['distance'] < $b['distance'];
    }" 
);

usort( $items, $sort_dist );
```

Gives an error: `syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

Removing the references to `['distance']` and `['order-dir']` removes this error.

Does anyone know how to use `create_function` with nested arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `create_function` in this instance. You can also write it like this:

```
function sort_by_distance($a, $b) {
    if( $a['order-dir'] == 'asc' ) {
        return $a['distance'] > $b['distance'];
    }
    else {
        return $a['distance'] < $b['distance'];
    }
}

usort( $items, "sort_by_distance" ); // pass the function name as a string
```

Comment: Not my code ;) - if you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your variable names. Per the [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Usually these parameters will be passed as single quote delimited strings. The reason for using single quoted strings, is to protect the variable names from parsing, *otherwise, if you use double quotes there will be a need to escape the variable names, e.g. `\$avar`*.

I should note for future readers that [Frits van Campen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10590911/350278) is probably the solution you should use, but if you absolutely need to use `create_function`, my answer should work.

Comment: Didn't try this but it probably would have worked as well, thanks.